# Defining a ball

Tags: terminology, article-writing

Which are appropriate phrases to define a ball?

1. Let $B$ be the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$.
2. Let $B$ be the open ball of radius $r$ around $x$.
3. Let $B$ be the open ball of radius $r$ about $x$.
4. Let $B$ be the open ball of radius $r$ with the center at $x$.

Comment: @Sinusz All of them are acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of them are acceptable, in context, but you may want to refrain from $4$ and $2$. $4$ is just a wordy variation of $1$ and is unnecessary. The most common ways to phrase such a problem is through standard notation:

$$B_r (x)$$ is generally understood to be the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$.

Try to refrain from ambiguities or unnecessary wording.

Comment: And then some people write $B_x(r)$ to mean the same thing... luckily the usage of letter $r$ for radius reduces the ambiguity.